# Recover Dell Factory Restory Image on Secret Drive

Tags: disk-image, dell-studio

I have an Studio 17, which has a secret 15 gigabyte partition with the original Windows 7 recovery image. Is there any way I can convert this into a recovery DVD so that I can delete the partition.

I am trying to install a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows 7 so I want to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

On my **Dell Inspirion 15R SE** I have a software called **"Dell Backup and Recovery"**. Here you can select to backup the recovery files to an USB drive. Look if you also have this software installed.

Comment: once before i had restored to facotry settings looks like its not installed after that :(

Comment: you can download the tool from the following Dell website: http://www.dellbackupandrecovery.com/en-US/Index.html